# C# SQL How to select and process N records, and then update them?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I retrieve some records by running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] order by [Date] OFFSET N ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
```

Where N is a number that starts from 0 and increment by 500. There are multiple instances of this application and each instance gets 500 records.

Now the question is, how do I update the retrieved records? The records don't have primary key. I tried something like this but the syntax isn't right:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [status] = 1 order by [Date] OFFSET N ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS
```

Note: I can't use WHERE status = 0 because I want one instance to only deal with the records it retrieved.

Any idea?

Comment: "The records don't have primary key" Then there's no way to reliably update them.  Is there no value or combination of values that you can use to identify a record?

Comment: In any case you need to add a primary key, even if it is an auto-increment number that doesn't have any real meaning other than to identify the record.

Comment: [MSDN: Sql Server Create Primary Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the comments. I can't assume there is primary key. I don't have full control over this database.

Comment: Is there any column or combination of columns that would uniquely identify a row, what are you setting the `status` for, is there perhaps a `name` column that is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE x
 SET [status] = 1
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM [MyTable] order by [Date] OFFSET N ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
      ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE x
SET x.[status] = 1
OUTPUT deleted.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM [MyTable] 
        WHERE 
            [status] = 0 
        ORDER BY [Date] 
        OFFSET N ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
    ) x;
```

Be careful though, your "fetch next" is preventing any rows from being returned if there are not at least 500 to return. Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: I just tried it when there is only 1 record to return with FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY. And that one record was successfully returned.